# Clausulas whereIn e whereNotIn

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tenho duas tabelas, uma tenho as disciplinas e a outra tenho as periodo_disciplinas, efetuo filtro no curso e no periodo. Preciso trazer apenas as disciplinas que não estão lançadas na tabela de periodo_disciplinas, para o usuário poder adicionar essas disciplinas que não estao lançadas, poderiam me explicar como funciona o whereIn e o whereNotIn do laravel porque nao consigo fazer funcionar, em vezde ele me trazer 5 que é o correto ele me traz apenas 3.

Segue código

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Periodo_disciplinas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Disciplinas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Periodos Letivos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor coloque código e não imagem, a parte das tabelas tudo bem, mas, a parte de código coloque o texto e utilize a ferramenta de formatação

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses) e o [whereInNot](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses) precisa no primeiro parâmetro o nome do campo e no segundo parâmetro o `array simples`, ***exemplo*** `[1,2,3]`.

No seu código precisa de um ajuste porque o `get` retorna um dado complexo, ou seja, diferente do que o [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses)/[whereInNot](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses) ***precisa***, utilize o método [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck) e no final o método `toArray()`, ***exemplo***:

```
$disciplinas_id_in_periodos = PeriodoDisciplina::
      where('periodo_letivos_id', '=', $periodo_letivo->id)
      ->select('disciplina_id')
      ->pluck('disciplina_id')
      ->toArray();

$disciplinas = Disciplina::where('id','like','%%')
     ->where('cursos_id','=',$cursos_id)
     ->select('id')
     ->pluck('id')
     ->toArray();
```

agora as duas variáveis (`$disciplinas_id_in_periodos` e `$disciplinas`) são `array simples` e vai funcionar o que precisa.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses)
- [whereInNot](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses)
- [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck)